# make directory if it doesn't exist with `mogrify -path` command

Tags: imagemagick

I convert images in a directory named `foo` to `bar` by like this.

```
$ mkdir bar
$ mogrify -path bar -negate foo/*.png
```

Is there option in Imagemagick that create a folder with `-path` option, if it not exist.

Comment: `mkdir -p /path/to/bar` makes parents only as needed.

Comment: I asked about option of `mogrify` not option of `mkdir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take arguments from the `mogrify` command, and do other actions based on their content, you can "override" the program with a function of your own, then pass the original arguments on to the function:

```
mymog(){
   [[ $1 == "-path" ]] && [[ ! -d $2 ]] && mkdir "$2" 
   mogrify "$@"
}
```

To use it, just replace `mymog` wherever you would use `mogrify`:

```
mymog -path bar -negate foo/*.png
```

The function tests to see if the first argument is `-path`. If so, it goes on to test if the second argument is *not* an existing directory. If it is not, then it creates that directory. (The `[[ ]] &&` is just another way to write if-then statements.) *In either case* it goes on to pass all the arguments to the `mogrify` command.

The only warning is that you have to put the `-path` argument first -- you can't stick it elsewhere in the line. You should be able to use this wherever you would normally use `mogrify` and it will just ignore the `mkdir` part if there is no `-path` definition.

To have this available in your daily usage, add those 4 lines to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file, depending on your operating system.

**EDIT #2:** New answer with no dependence on position of `-path`

```
function mogmod(){
    args=("$@")
    for ((i=0; i < $#; i++)) {
       if [[ ${args[$i]} = "-path" ]]
       then 
           mypath=${args[((i+1))]}
           [[ ! -d "$mypath" ]] && mkdir "$mypath" 
       fi
    }
    mogrify "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thanks beroe! I can wrap `mogrify` like that. But I don't know how to wrap `mogrify` only when `-path` argument exists. It would be very helpful if you show me how.

Comment: If you put `testmake ;` in front of `mogrify -negate foo/*.png` without the `-path` element, it will just make the directory if it doesn't exist, but the `mogrify` command will run independent of `testmake`. Basically, you can add that whenever you are using `-path` or omit it if not, but it shouldn't hurt anything to use it all the time. (Maybe I am not understanding your typical use.)

Comment: Thanks your advice. But I want to make directory only when the option `-path` is given.

Comment: OK, I see what you want now and have updated the answer to do that. You probably would have gotten 5 replies in 5 minutes if you had tagged this as `shell` or `bash` with the title "How to re-use arguments from a shell command to perform other functions" ;^)

Comment: I'm really grateful that you write the function. But I don't use it if there is a condition that the `-path` must be the first argument. I know I'll forget the rule if I use the function once in a month.

Comment: You drive a hard bargain! I added a version that checks each parameter, and finds -path wherever it might occur, then uses the next param as the directory name. Please test first in a test directory...

Comment: Fantastic! I works exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much!